# Populating Content Control in Word document with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word

I have a Word template (*.dotx) I am trying to populate using C#.

I cannot access the "Plain Text Content Controls" in the template.

The following code that adds(opens) the document but it always shows 0 formfields.

**References used:**

```
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
using Document = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
```

**Functional code:**

```
var word = new Application();
var doc = new Document();
doc = word.Documents.Add(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +
             @"\..\..\Media\Documents\MCO Notification of a Medicaid Other Event - Template.dotx");
doc.Activate();

MessageBox.Show(doc.FormFields.Count.ToString());

doc.Close();
word.Quit();
```

Also, how do I insert a relative path to the document within the application.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a [FlowDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) to accommodate the RTF from the Word document.

Search for solutions regarding "showing a Word document inside a WPF FlowDocument".

Something like this : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649064/Show-Word-File-in-WPF